# Whether this specific example is undefined behavior for restrict keyword from C99?

Tags: c, gcc

I went through all answers but I can't get the answer about whether the following example is undefined behavior.
It's the same example as in 6.7.3.1 of C99 spec.

EXAMPLE 3 The function parameter declarations

```
void h(int n, int * restrict p, int * restrict q, int * restrict r)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p[i] = q[i] + r[i];
}
```

illustrate how an unmodified object can be aliased through two restricted pointers. In particular, if a and b are disjoint arrays, a call of the form h(100, a, b, b) has defined behavior, because array b is not modified within function h.

**In short, it is explicitly mentioned it's defined behavior if b is not modified within function h. However, whether is it undefined behavior if a call of the form `h(100, a, a, b)`?**

A little bit more backgrounds why I want to make it clear. There are some basic functions which we want to use in in-place or out-of-place manner. In order to reduce the effort, it is desired if we don't need to provide both `h(int n, int * restrict p, int * restrict q, int * restrict r)` and `h_inplace(int n, int * restrict p, int * restrict q)`. From current observation, it seems gcc, clang, icc, msvc can give correct result even if we call it as the form of `h(100, a, a, b)`. However, we definitely don't want to have the risk if it is undefined behavior (which means it may be wrong from other compilers or future versions of gcc, clang, icc, msvc). What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

`h(100, a, a, b)` obviously causes UB because `p` and `q` were promised not to alias each other, and the code writes through one of them.  See C11 6.7.3.1/4:

> If `L` is used to access the value of the object `X` that it designates, **and `X` is also modified (by any means)**, then the following requirements apply: [...] Every other lvalue used to access the value of `X` shall also have its address based on `P`

Writing through `p` accesses the value of an object (called `X` here), and modifies it. Therefore every lvalue used to access the object within the function must be generated from `p`.  However `q` is not generated from `p`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a hint to the code optimizer. Using restrict ensures it that it can store a pointer variable in a CPU register and not have to flush an update of the pointer value to memory so that an alias is updated as well.

Whether or not it takes advantage of it depends heavily on implementation details of the optimizer and the CPU. Code optimizers already are heavily invested in detecting non-aliasing since it is such an important optimization.

However, if the restrict keyword is used and the function is declared as

```
void updatePtrs(size_t *restrict ptrA, size_t *restrict ptrB, size_t *restrict val);
```

then the compiler is allowed to assume that ptrA, ptrB, and val point to different locations and updating one pointer will not affect the other pointers. The programmer, not the compiler, is responsible for ensuring that the pointers do not point to identical locations.

If as a programmer you are not ensuring that ptrA , ptrB points to different location then it is obvious you are breaking the rule which may result into undefined behavior .

Comment: Read carefully before judging whether I am incorrect or not . OP example may result into undefined behavior whereas I was talking about the standard .

Comment: @Richard Han : Welcome . sometimes , compiler optimization may save you from undefined result but as per my understanding it is something programmer should  take care else undefined behavior . we can't completely rely on compiler optimization .Here is the wiki link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict for more details .

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly clear, as the M.M's first answer states, that h(100, a, a, b) is undefined behavior, but it is possible to create a low-overhead version of h that does have defined behavior (IMO: I'm currently having an argument with Richard about this.)

```
void h2(int n, int * restrict p, int * restrict q_opt, int * restrict r)
{
    int i;
    int * restrict q = (p == q_opt) ? p : q_opt;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p[i] = q[i] + r[i];
}
```

An even simpler version (but which requires the caller to know the magic value) has the new line:

```
int * restrict q = q_opt ? q_opt : p;
```

and the caller gets the in-place behavior by calling h2(100, a, 0, b).

In both cases the q pointer is either distinct from p according to the rules of restrict or derived from p (and not q), and so no conflict arises.

In particular, the discussion and rationale in the standard are actually pretty good, I think.  The reason for the restriction is that faster code can sometimes be made by first copying any of the data addressed by a restrict pointer into another memory space (per argument) operating on it there, and then copying the results back.  This is particularly true when the extra memory copy is into registers, and doubly true when the compiler is allowed to unroll loops, all of which are good go-fast tools.

The strategy here clearly works fine when a source at q_opt is copied to another location before being used (before use, outside the loop), whether it refers to p or to a different array.  It would clearly fail if the user called h2(100, a+1, a, r), because that would still be a violation of the rules of restrict.